# explain the performance difference between these two queries

Tags: postgresql

This is a followup to: [grouping multiple queries into a single one, with Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71489793/grouping-multiple-queries-into-a-single-one-with-postgres/71496029#71496029)

I have a simple table:

```
instrument     VARCHAR                     NOT NULL,
ts             TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
quantity       FLOAT8                      NOT NULL,
price          FLOAT8                      NOT NULL,
direction      INTEGER                     NOT NULL
```

and the following query:

```
SELECT instrument, ts, price, quantity, direction FROM binance.trades t
JOIN (VALUES
    ('BTCUSDT','2022-03-16 12:00:00'::timestamp),
    ('ETHUSDT','2022-03-16 12:00:00'::timestamp),
    ('BCHUSDT','2022-03-16 12:00:00'::timestamp),
    ('XRPUSDT','2022-03-16 12:00:00'::timestamp),
    ('EOSUSDT','2022-03-16 12:00:00'::timestamp),
    ('LTCUSDT','2022-03-16 12:00:00'::timestamp),
    ('TRXUSDT','2022-03-16 12:00:00'::timestamp),
    ('ETCUSDT','2022-03-16 12:00:00'::timestamp),
    ('LINKUSDT','2022-03-16 12:00:00'::timestamp),
    ('XLMUSDT','2022-03-16 12:00:00'::timestamp),
    ('ADAUSDT','2022-03-16 12:00:00'::timestamp),
    ('XMRUSDT','2022-03-16 12:00:00'::timestamp),
    ('XTZUSDT','2022-03-16 12:00:00'::timestamp),
    ('BNBUSDT','2022-03-16 12:00:00'::timestamp),
    ('ATOMUSDT','2022-03-16 12:00:00'::timestamp),
    ('VETUSDT','2022-03-16 12:00:00'::timestamp),
    ('THETAUSDT','2022-03-16 12:00:00'::timestamp),
    ('ALGOUSDT','2022-03-16 12:00:00'::timestamp),
    ('DOGEUSDT','2022-03-16 12:00:00'::timestamp),
    ('SNXUSDT','2022-03-16 12:00:00'::timestamp),
    ('DOTUSDT','2022-03-16 12:00:00'::timestamp),
    ('RUNEUSDT','2022-03-16 12:00:00'::timestamp),
    ('SUSHIUSDT','2022-03-16 12:00:00'::timestamp),
    ('EGLDUSDT','2022-03-16 12:00:00'::timestamp),
    ('SOLUSDT','2022-03-16 12:00:00'::timestamp),
    ('UNIUSDT','2022-03-16 12:00:00'::timestamp),
    ('AVAXUSDT','2022-03-16 12:00:00'::timestamp),
    ('LUNAUSDT','2022-03-16 12:00:00'::timestamp)
) AS params(i, f)
ON t.instrument = params.i AND t.ts >= params.f
WHERE ts < '2022-03-16 12:01:00'
ORDER BY instrument, ts;
```

When I execute this query, I get this:

```
Merge Join  (cost=1.59..1010782.11 rows=4416888 width=36) (actual time=450.791..8926.179 rows=4971 loops=1)
"  Output: t.instrument, t.ts, t.price, t.quantity, t.direction"
"  Merge Cond: ((t.instrument)::text = ""*VALUES*"".column1)"
"  Join Filter: (t.ts >= ""*VALUES*"".column2)"
  Rows Removed by Join Filter: 15041834
  ->  Index Scan using idx_trades_instrument_ts on binance.trades t  (cost=0.56..732753.74 rows=18456284 width=36) (actual time=0.014..4838.303 rows=17976183 loops=1)
"        Output: t.instrument, t.ts, t.quantity, t.price, t.direction"
        Index Cond: (t.ts < '2022-03-16 12:01:00'::timestamp without time zone)
  ->  Sort  (cost=1.02..1.09 rows=28 width=40) (actual time=0.032..708.933 rows=14950420 loops=1)
"        Output: ""*VALUES*"".column1, ""*VALUES*"".column2"
"        Sort Key: ""*VALUES*"".column1"
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 26kB
"        ->  Values Scan on ""*VALUES*""  (cost=0.00..0.35 rows=28 width=40) (actual time=0.002..0.009 rows=28 loops=1)"
"              Output: ""*VALUES*"".column1, ""*VALUES*"".column2"
Query Identifier: -4392899169609901608
Planning Time: 0.486 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 11
"  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true"
"  Timing: Generation 4.170 ms, Inlining 2.702 ms, Optimization 36.359 ms, Emission 20.524 ms, Total 63.754 ms"
Execution Time: 8930.599 ms
```

However, if I remove a single instrument from the query, I get that (almost the smae number of rows in the output)

```
Sort  (cost=980284.81..990936.32 rows=4260601 width=36) (actual time=81.722..81.907 rows=4907 loops=1)
"  Output: t.instrument, t.ts, t.price, t.quantity, t.direction"
"  Sort Key: t.instrument, t.ts"
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 576kB
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.56..377992.71 rows=4260601 width=36) (actual time=76.345..78.216 rows=4907 loops=1)
"        Output: t.instrument, t.ts, t.price, t.quantity, t.direction"
"        ->  Values Scan on ""*VALUES*""  (cost=0.00..0.34 rows=27 width=40) (actual time=0.005..0.019 rows=27 loops=1)"
"              Output: ""*VALUES*"".column1, ""*VALUES*"".column2"
        ->  Index Scan using idx_trades_instrument_ts on binance.trades t  (cost=0.56..12421.72 rows=157800 width=36) (actual time=0.010..0.052 rows=182 loops=27)
"              Output: t.instrument, t.ts, t.quantity, t.price, t.direction"
"              Index Cond: (((t.instrument)::text = ""*VALUES*"".column1) AND (t.ts >= ""*VALUES*"".column2) AND (t.ts < '2022-03-16 12:01:00'::timestamp without time zone))"
Query Identifier: 8658371483566561811
Planning Time: 0.501 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 6
"  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true"
"  Timing: Generation 4.031 ms, Inlining 32.303 ms, Optimization 30.705 ms, Emission 13.192 ms, Total 80.232 ms"
Execution Time: 86.182 ms
```

Between 27 and 28 instruments, with almost the same number of rows in the output there is a 100x slowdown.

I'm not experienced enough with SQL to understand the analyzer's output, but I can clearly see that one more entry in the list is changing what's happening.

What could be the reason?

---

Here is the details with 3x 't.instrument = params.i'

```
Merge Join  (cost=1.59..1390428.62 rows=6957315 width=36) (actual time=797.882..13886.750 rows=6443 loops=1)
"  Output: t.instrument, t.ts, t.price, t.quantity, t.direction"
"  Merge Cond: ((t.instrument)::text = ""*VALUES*"".column1)"
"  Join Filter: (t.ts >= ""*VALUES*"".column2)"
  Rows Removed by Join Filter: 23064176
  ->  Index Scan using idx_trades_instrument_ts on binance.trades t  (cost=0.56..952489.47 rows=29071637 width=36) (actual time=0.043..7520.115 rows=28524631 loops=1)
"        Output: t.instrument, t.ts, t.quantity, t.price, t.direction"
        Index Cond: (t.ts < '2022-03-17 12:01:00'::timestamp without time zone)
  ->  Sort  (cost=1.02..1.09 rows=28 width=40) (actual time=0.032..1094.202 rows=22928388 loops=1)
"        Output: ""*VALUES*"".column1, ""*VALUES*"".column2"
"        Sort Key: ""*VALUES*"".column1"
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 26kB
"        ->  Values Scan on ""*VALUES*""  (cost=0.00..0.35 rows=28 width=40) (actual time=0.003..0.010 rows=28 loops=1)"
"              Output: ""*VALUES*"".column1, ""*VALUES*"".column2"
Query Identifier: 7068233849071501838
Planning Time: 0.524 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 11
"  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true"
"  Timing: Generation 4.546 ms, Inlining 13.998 ms, Optimization 59.605 ms, Emission 20.946 ms, Total 99.094 ms"
Execution Time: 13891.608 ms
```

Comment: The reason is the bad estimate for the index scan on `trades`.

Comment: Is it something I can have an impact on?

Comment: Perhaps it helps to have the same condition twice: `ON t.instrument = params.i AND t.instrument = params.i`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, it does speed things up; what does it do? but in the end, the improved speed is still closer to the slow performing one than the fast one.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the execution plan. What if you use the same condition three times?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, with 3x the condition, it's the same as 2x; but for some reason, this became fast and when I changed the timestamp, it went back to slow again, so maybe it's caching, right now it returns the same with 1x, 2x or 3x the condition, which is 14s (vs. 8s during the night). I've edited the question with the info from explain.

Comment: Must be a caching effect, because the plan stays the same.